# Changing transparency of items inside array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-ui, jquery-transit

What I want to do is change the transparancy of the jpg's. I have put my ul li img inside an array.

[image]

When I click an image I can see in my console, the position of the clicked image, inside the array.

[image]

Now when I click an Image I'd like to change the transparency of that image and also the transparency of the images who precede the clicked image.

So for example: when I click the image who is positioned at 4 inside the array. I want the transparency set to 1 for items 0,1,2,3 and 4 inside the array. How can I access the css of the clicked item of an array?

**HTML**

```
<ul id="people">
    <li><img src="person.jpg" alt="person" id="img1"></li>
    <li><img src="person.jpg" alt="person" id="img2"></li>
    <li><img src="person.jpg" alt="person" id="img3"></li>
    <li><img src="person.jpg" alt="person" id="img4"></li>
    <li><img src="person.jpg" alt="person" id="img5"></li>
    <li><img src="person.jpg" alt="person" id="img6"></li>
    <li><img src="person.jpg" alt="person" id="img7"></li>
    <li><img src="person.jpg" alt="person" id="img8"></li>
    <li><img src="person.jpg" alt="person" id="img9"></li>
    <li><img src="person.jpg" alt="person" id="img10"></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
}

img{
    width: 90px;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**JS**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('ul').transition({ opacity: 0.1, delay: 500 });

    jQuery(function(){
        var peopleArray = [];

        $('#people li img').each(function(){
            peopleArray.push(this);
        })
        console.log(peopleArray);

        $('ul li img').click(function() {
            console.log(($('ul li img').index(this)));
        });
    });
```

**LIBRARY**

I'm using jquery-transit:

http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

Comment: You're complicating it -> **http://jsfiddle.net/9ok9kdqd/1/**

Comment: Don't you need to put the images inside an array for when you want to change the transparency? For instance if you clicked image 5, but you were wrong and you wanted to press image 4? How can you go back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#people li img').on("click",function() { 
  // you likely also want to reset
  $(this).closest("ul")
    .find("img").transition({ opacity: 0.1, delay: 500 });
  $(this).closest("li").prevUntil().andSelf()
    .find("img").transition({ opacity: 1, delay: 500 }); 
});
```

You may want to put one inside the callback to not have a blinking update